# Pandas: how to find values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes `df` and `df1`.

```
df = 
    Days        0   2   4   5   7   8   10  
0   2012-01-01  27  30  5   34  1   2   10  


df1 = 

      Lat      Lon         ID
0   1.3678  103.9826        0
1   1.4166  103.8654        1
2   1.3399  103.8878        2
3   1.3455  103.6806        3
4   1.3764  103.8492        3
5   1.3337  103.7768        5
6   1.4439  103.7854        6
7   1.2500  103.8279        7
8   1.3302  103.7205        8
9   1.3134  103.9619        9
10  1.2799  103.8703        10
```

I want find the values of the column of `df` in `df1` and return:

```
df2 =

     Lat     Lon       val  ID
0   1.3678  103.9826    27  0
1   1.4166  103.8654    30  2
2   1.3399  103.8878    5   3
3   1.3455  103.6806    34  5
4   1.3764  103.8492    1   7
5   1.3337  103.7768    2   8
6   1.4439  103.7854    10  10
```

this is what I am doing

```
for i in range(1, len(df.columns)):
    c = l[i] ## name of the colum
    z = np.int(c)
    tmp1 = df1[df1.ID==z]
    df2.Lat[i-1] = tmp1.Lat[tmp1.index[0]]
    df2.Lon[i-1] = tmp1.Lon[tmp1.index[0]]
    df2.val[i-1] = df[c][tmp.index[0]]
    df2.ID[i-1]  = c
```

Comment: Does it work? What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, create a `dff` with transposed data and merge it on `ID`

```
In [56]: dff = pd.DataFrame({'ID': df.columns[1:].astype(int), 'V': df.values[0][1:]})

In [57]: dff
Out[57]:
   ID   V
0   0  27
1   2  30
2   4   5
3   5  34
4   7   1
5   8   2
6  10  10

In [58]: df1.merge(dff)
Out[58]:
      Lat       Lon  ID   V
0  1.3678  103.9826   0  27
1  1.3399  103.8878   2  30
2  1.3337  103.7768   5  34
3  1.2500  103.8279   7   1
4  1.3302  103.7205   8   2
5  1.2799  103.8703  10  10
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your resulting dataframe doesn't appear to follow from the first two.  It looks like you're using the column headers from `df` to merge on the `ID` in `df1`, but you give ID=3 a value of 5, which doesn't add up.  All the others do though, so I'm assuming it's a mistake in the example.

Second, you should almost never be working in Pandas using a looping-indexing construct like that.  It's very error-prone, and very slow, and is probably available in a much more efficient way.  This, I assume, is your question.

Here's the code I used:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({0:[27], 2:[30], 4:[5], 7:[1], 8:[2], 10:[10]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Lat':[1.3678,1.4166,1.3399,1.3455,1.3764,1.3337,1.4439,1.2500,1.3302,1.3134,1.2799], 
                    'ID':[0,1,2,3,3,5,6,7,8,9,10]})

df2 = df1.merge(df.T.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'ID', 0:'val'}), how='outer')
```

It starts by transposing the first dataframe using `.T`, then pulls the index out as a column, so it looks like this:

```
In [70]: df.T.reset_index()
Out[70]:
   index   0
0      0  27
1      2  30
2      4   5
3      7   1
4      8   2
5     10  10
```

Then it renames 'index' to 'ID' and 0 to 'val', then merges on `ID` for the final result:

```
In [71]: df2
Out[71]:
      ID     Lat   val
0    0.0  1.3678  27.0
1    1.0  1.4166   NaN
2    2.0  1.3399  30.0
3    3.0  1.3455   NaN
4    3.0  1.3764   NaN
5    5.0  1.3337   NaN
6    6.0  1.4439   NaN
7    7.0  1.2500   1.0
8    8.0  1.3302   2.0
9    9.0  1.3134   NaN
10  10.0  1.2799  10.0
11   4.0     NaN   5.0
```

I used `how='outer'` to emphasize the areas where you have to refine your criteria a bit better.  What should happen with the double occurrence of ID 3?  Or the values that don't occur on the other side?  You can see the different options you have for `how` [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).